# R - Replacing values in dataframes with conditional statements and substrings

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, grepl

I have a dataframe df

[image]

In this is a large dataframe with hundreds of columns of data. In particular is 40 columns of data with similar names TD1, TD2 ..... TD40. I would like to scan each row and if any value begins with Z50 I would like the row value in the column Category to change to "Surgery". Hence in the above example rows 1 and 3 would convert from "Cardiac" to "Surgery".

In a similar example when the entire code was Z50 I used:

```
df %>%
rowwise()%>%
mutate(Category = if(any(c_across(starts_with("TD")) == "Z50")) 
                   "Surgery" else Category)
```

Now I just want the first 3 characters to equal Z50. I assume I would use a grepl function but not sure how to incorporate it into the original code. Well it hasn't work for me so far.
Any ideas?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `apply` and `grepl` for a base R option:

```r
idx_start <- grep("^TD1$", names(df))
idx_end   <- grep("^TD40$", names(df))

df$Category <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    ifelse(sum(grepl("^Z50", x[idx_start:idx_end])) > 0,
           "Surgery", df$Category)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Your suggestion appears to work. However I get a message saying "there were 50 or more warnings" after the code executes. Is there anything that should cause me concern?

Comment: @dapdot1 Best thing might be to look at the warnings.  Most likely, they would have to do with implicit conversions and similar things.  The most important thing is that the result generated matches your expectations.

Comment: on closer inspection the code hasn't worked. It appears to have correctly changed the column Category to "Surgery" when applicable. However it seems to inexplicably have changed all the other column values in Category to just "Cardiac" The first value in the column. So written over values such as "Stroke"  etc. Very odd,

Comment: I realised the code idx_start wouldn't differentiate between columns TD1 and TD11 and so may be part of the warning messages .

Comment: @dapdot1 Check the updated answer.  Grep for `^TD1$` etc.

Comment: thanks for your help but that didn't seem to work. Instead of getting "Surgery" when the ifelse command is true I get "Cardiac" in the Category column for every row. Note "Cardiac" was the first row value for that column in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @Tim the solution that work was just slight adjustment on what you proposed. The idx_start <- grep("^TD1$", names(df)) idx_start1 <- idx_start[1]
idx_end   <- grep("^TD40$", names(df))

df$Category <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    ifelse(sum(grepl("^Z50.^$", x[idx_start1:idx_end])) > 0, "Surgery", x['Category']
})

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code using `grepl` as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(Category = if(any(grepl('^Z50', c_across(starts_with("TD"))))) 
                       "Surgery" else Category)
```